# Sum the values retrieved from coreData and Display in section

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I want to add all the amount labels in a given section and display the total in the section header.
my table view looks like this.

Section Header - 12/07/2012

```
categoryName  Amount
 Groceries     100
  Social       100
```

Section Header - 10/04/2012

```
categoryName  Amount
  Gas          500
  Social       600
```

now i want to display the total 200 in the 1st section header.and 1100 in the next header

```
-(IBAction)bydate:(id)sender
{
[self.expenseArray removeAllObjects];
[self.expenseArrayCount removeAllObjects];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

for(NSManagedObject *records in self.listOfExpenses){
    NSString *compareDates = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[records valueForKey:@"date"]];
    BOOL isAvail = NO;
    for (int i = 0; i<[self.expenseArray count]; i++){
        if([compareDates isEqualToString:[self.expenseArray objectAtIndex:i]])
            isAvail = YES;
    }
    if(!isAvail)
        [self.expenseArray addObject:compareDates];
}
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < [self.expenseArray count] ; i ++){
    NSString *compareDates = [self.expenseArray objectAtIndex:i];
    for(NSManagedObject *info in self.listOfExpenses){
        if([compareDates isEqualToString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[info valueForKey:@"date"]]])
            count++;
    }
    [self.expenseArrayCount addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count]];
    count = 0;
}
[self.byDateTab reloadData];
[dateFormatter release];
}

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //not posting un necessary code.

    else if (tableView == self.byDateTab)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < [self.expenseArrayCount count];i++)
    {
        if(indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            NSManagedObject *records = nil;
            records = [self.listOfExpenses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            self.firstLabel.text = [records valueForKey:@"category"];
            self.secondLabel.text = [records valueForKey:@"details"];
            NSString *amountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[records valueForKey:@"amount"]];
            self.thirdLabel.text = amountString;
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == i)
        {
            int rowCount = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<indexPath.section; j++)
            {
                rowCount = rowCount + [[self.expenseArrayCount objectAtIndex:j]intValue];
            }
            NSManagedObject *records = nil;
            records = [self.listOfExpenses objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row + rowCount) ];
            self.firstLabel.text = [records valueForKey:@"category"];
            self.secondLabel.text = [records valueForKey:@"details"];
            NSString *amountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[records valueForKey:@"amount"]];
            self.thirdLabel.text = amountString;

        }
    }
}


-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSString *title = [[[NSString alloc]init]autorelease];
if(tableView == self.byDateTab)
    title =  [self.expenseArray objectAtIndex:section];
return title;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc]init] autorelease];
if(tableView == self.byDateTab){
    headerView.frame = CGRectMake(310, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30);
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:149.0/255 green:163.0/255 blue:173.0/255 alpha:1]];
    UILabel *leftLabel = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width-10, 18)]autorelease];
    leftLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    leftLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    leftLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:17.0];
    leftLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [headerView addSubview:leftLabel];

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    NSString *a = [formatter currencySymbol];

    UILabel *rightLabel = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width-10, 18)]autorelease];
    rightLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",a];
    rightLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    rightLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:17.0];
    rightLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [headerView addSubview:rightLabel];



}
```

Comment: You should try to write a method that iterates over the records of a section and returns the total amount. Your code is not easy to understand. I don't understand the purpose of the loops inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this method:
`- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`
It returns the title for the given section. 
So you need to figure out which records match the section number and iterate over the records to compute the total amount.
You may want to consider doing this out of the above method to not compute the total amount for each section each time this method is called.
You can create an array of "pre-computed" titles as soon as you load your data and only do this:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section  
{  
    return [titles objectAtIndex:section];  
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the code of this method?

Answer (score 0):

The logic is quite simple. I don't really want to go deep into your code, so this chunk will give you an explanation you need

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  NSArray *sectionArray = [mySectionsDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", section]];
  int total = 0;
  for (MyCustomCoreDataObject *object in sectionArray) {
    total += object.amount.intValue;
  }
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", total];
}
```

Comment: i didnt use any dictionary..i have updated my code ..please check

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**
(I see that you are not using fetchResultController and I do recommend using it as it will help you with this task and other tasks with table view that display core data entities).

**With fetchResultController:**

You should add a `totalAmount` NSString to your fetched entity (the entity that you fetch in the fetchResultController) class.

Then add the add operation to the class. inside create your calculation so you will get the total amount as a string.

```
-(NSString*)totalAmount{
   NSInteger amount = 0;
   //do your calculation here
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"amount = %i",amount];
}
```

and then in the fetch result controller pass the `totalAmount` as your section name key path this will return the `totalAmount` string for each section:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                    managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"totalAmount" cacheName:nil];
```

Then edit your section header methods so the table view will act correctly:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
     return ([[fetchedResultsController sections] count]);
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
      id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
```

lastly, set the amount text for each section from the fetch result controller:

```
 - (NSString *)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller sectionIndexTitleForSectionName:(NSString *)sectionName {
      return sectionName;
 }
```